# Leaflet: How can you find a polyline latlng point nearest a set mouse pointer perimeter?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with a polyline layer on it. There is a corresponding chart using charts.js for elevation along that same path. The two are disconnected datasets, but the indexes of each dataset match.

Currently, as I've written it, when you scrub the mouse over the elevation profile, a corresponding map marker tracks along the polyline. I'd like to allow the opposite as well--that is, the user hovers the mouse near the polyline and the corresponding elevation point lights up. All I really need is to retrieve the latlng(s) within X pixels of the mouse that exist on the polyline.

Is there an easy way of doing this with a leaflet utility?